# How to send values from blender to arduino?

Tags: python, serial-port

I'm new to blender and python.I want receive analog values from arduino to blender 3d.for that I'm used this code.I found this code on http://opendimension.blogspot.com/2009/04/bouncing-virtual-ball-with-arduino-and.html

According to his code, Blender software send character and tell arduino to send values.But when I'm trying run the code in blender it will print the error "Could not write to COM3!". There is no problem with the connecting to COM3 port.I'm using Arduino mega 2560.

Due to above problem arduino cannot send values to blender.Where did I get wrong??

```
port = 'COM3' 
pin = 0 

try: 
    GameLogic.SerialPort 
except: 
    try: 
        GameLogic.SerialPort = serial.Serial(port,9600,timeout=1)  
        print 'Port ' + port + 'found!' 

        #ok, we have a port. Let's test if we can write to it 
        try: 
            GameLogic.SerialPort.write('x') 
            GameLogic.serialRead = False 
            GameLogic.serialOk = True 

        except: 
            GameLogic.serialOk = False 
            print 'could not write to port ' + port + '!' 


    except: 
        GameLogic.serialOk = False 
        print 'no port ' + port + ' found!' 



# do stuff if serial port is OK 
if GameLogic.serialOk: 
    if GameLogic.serialRead: 
        valo = GameLogic.SerialPort.readline() 
        val = float(valo)/100 
        GameLogic.serialRead = False     
    else: 
        GameLogic.SerialPort.write('a') 
        GameLogic.serialRead = True     


    # BLENDER stuff 
    if GameLogic.serialRead == False: 
        objs = GameLogic.getCurrentScene().getObjectList() 
        cube = objs["OBbox"] 
        cube.setPosition([1.0,1.0,val])


Arduino code


int analogPin=0;
int analogVal=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if ( Serial.available()) {
    char ch = Serial.read();
    if ('a'==ch) {
      analogVal = analogRead(analogPin);
      Serial.println(analogVal);
    }
  }
}
```

I connect arduino to 'COM3' and install "py-serial" and I try to send data from arduino without using request/respond method and It works fine.But it always sends data.to avoid that i want to use this method.

Comment: I only include py-serial.Do i need to install any other software?

Comment: No one knows what you did wrong, since you swallow *all* exceptions.